# Python underscore variable

Tags: python, variables

In interactive python, there is the 'continuation variable', the underscore.

```
>>> import netlib
>>> netdev = netlib.netface('eth1')
>>> if netdev.getIP():
...    print _
... 
10.80.22.100
>>>
```

But using this in a script, it is undefined so this fails:

```
if netdev.getIP(): SetValue('ipaddress', _)
```

Is there something similar or a way to enable this for scripts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It is only available within the Python REPL.

Comment: Bummer! I figured, I was just hoping for a clean work around or alternative.  Thanks :)

Comment: "clean work around"?  Isn't that what the assignment statement is?

Comment: I have to set a lot of values- I was just hoping to keep each function to a single line- without making it crazy long or to hard to read.  I figured out a clear way to write it. Thanks =)