# Python for-loop without index and item

Tags: python, for-loop, pep8

Is it possible in python to have a for-loop without index and item?
I have something like the following:

```
list_1 = []
for i in range(5):
    list_1.append(3)
```

The code above works fine, but is not nice according to the pep8 coding guidelines. 
It says: "Unused variable 'i'".

Is there a way to make a for-loop (no while-loop) without having neither the index nor the item? Or should I ignore the coding guidelines?

Comment: if you won't use the variable, you should use '_' for convention.

Comment: Not an answer to the question in general, but in this specific example, you could do `list_1 = [3] * 5`.

Comment: I'll elaborate on @tobias_k's comment by saying that, in my opinion, a good rule to keep in mind is that if you find yourself in this kind of situation then for loop is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: Can someone point me to _where_ it says this in PEP8? I'm not disagreeing, it's just that I can't find it anywhere [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @SiHa, install pylint and run it over your code.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: Thanks, useful link, but that wasn't my question. PEP doesn't say anything about this, that I can see. Am I missing something?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think there is anything in pep8 specifically about having to use `_` when you have an unused variable in a loop, I don't ever get a pep8 coding style violation warning about it either on pycharm.

Comment: @SiHa I couldn't find it either. This thread also answers a somewhat similar question and some people also said they could not find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486148/unused-variable-naming-in-python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Better than that, it doesn't mention unused variables at all ` _ ` or otherwise. @Tonio: Thanks for the link. I think I'll stick with `i` (& `j` etc. in nested loops / comprehensions) though.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can replace `i` with `_` to make it an 'invisible' variable.

See related: [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python).

Comment: A comment in the accepted answer of the question you linked suggests using __ (double underscore) and this is perfect: it does not collide with gettext and gets rid of the "Unused variable" warning.

Answer (score 8):

While @toine is completly right about using `_`, you could also refine this by means of a list comprehension:

```py
list_1 = [3 for _ in range(5)]
```

This avoids the ITM ("initialize, than modify") anti-pattern.