# list comprehensions syntax with comma

Tags: python, list-comprehension

can you explain this code

```py
[y for _, y in ((1,2),(3,4))]
```

output is
`[2, 4]`

I do not find a document to use this syntax, but it can be run.

Comment: The source list contains 2-element tuples so we need to assign two variables to the output, for example we can have `x, y` or `foo, bar` but in this case we don't care about the first one so we assign it to a throwaway variable name `_`

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[y for _, y in ((1,2),(3,4))]` is a [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

This is equivalent to below `for`:

```
In [2935]: l = []

In [2936]: for _, y in ((1,2),(3,4)):
      ...:     l.append(y)
      ...: 
      ...: 

In [2937]: l
Out[2937]: [2, 4]
```

Also `_` is a [*throw-away*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486148/unused-variable-naming-in-python) variable, which means variables you are using while iterating but not really using them for any other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you break down the phrase `((1,2),(3,4))` you end up with a `tuple` of two `tuple`s.

So the iteration goes over the outer `tuple`, taking the first item in `_` and the second in `y`, from which you take only the second variable, `y`, and create a new `list`.

This is as same as this code, which is easier to grasp first:

```
my_set = ((1,2), (3,4))
my_list = []
for _, y in myset:
    my_list.append(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I convert code to

```py
[y for             x,y in ((1,2),(3,4))]
```

it is easy to understand
`_` is equal `x`

`,` is in the second statement

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively expand the code as

```py
t = ((1,2),(3,4))
print([y for x, y in t])
```

Here, replacing `x` with `_` gives back the original one-liner

Answer (score 0):

```
print([item for item in (("id", 1), ("name", "Yao Yuan"))])
# Output: [('id', 1), ('name', 'Yao Yuan')]
print([(item[0], item[1]) for item in (("id", 1), ("name", "Yao Yuan"))])
# Output: [('id', 1), ('name', 'Yao Yuan')]
print([(key, value) for key, value in (("id", 1), ("name", "Yao Yuan"))])
# Output: [('id', 1), ('name', 'Yao Yuan')]
print([key for key, value in (("id", 1), ("name", "Yao Yuan"))])
# Output: ['id', 'name']
print([value for key, value in (("id", 1), ("name", "Yao Yuan"))])
# Output: [1, 'Yao Yuan']
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax with comma `x1, x2, ...., xn = (y1, y2, ...., yn)` is used to **unpack an iterable of length n into n individual variables**. The undescore used during unpacking iterables is to say that you don't care about the value in a certain index of the iterable you are unpacking.

so basically, your example is using a list comprehension in which you first unpack each index in the iterable `((1,2),(3,4))` into variables `_, y` (where _ means disregarding index 0), then you comprehend all y variables into a list = [2, 4]

```py
[y for _, y in ((1,2),(3,4))]
```